# directX 2D microsoft c++ exception, why does it happened?

Tags: com, directx-11

I got microsoft c++ exception. I don't know it and i want to know what is wrong and how can i solve it.
And exception also happen when i write only CoInitialize(NULL) and CoUninitialize();

i think visual studio option is wrong but i can't find out how to fix it.
please help me.

1. I found two exception before call "CoInitialize(NULL);" (before CoInitialize line 29)

> exception :
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x008FEE98.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FEC84.

2. I found many exception when i create rendertarget. (line 54)

> exception :
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF244.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF244.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF4CC.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF4CC.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF244.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF244.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF4CC.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF4CC.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF244.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF244.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF4CC.
> Exception thrown at 0x75C2EB22 in WindowsProject1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x008FF4CC.

on microsoft sample code, i have write only CoInitialize, CoUninitialize, create, release D2D1Factory and HwndRenderTarget.

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "WindowsProject1.h"

#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1helper.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "d2d1");

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HWND hWnd;
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    
        // TODO: Place code here.
    
        // Initialize global strings
        LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
        LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
        MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    
        // Perform application initialization:
        if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    
        HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1));
    
        MSG msg;
    
        ID2D1Factory* p_factory;
        ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* p_renderTarget;
    
        D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &p_factory);
        p_factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
            D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
            D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hWnd, D2D1::SizeU(1000, 1000)),
            &p_renderTarget
        );
    
        p_factory->Release();
        p_renderTarget->Release();
    
        // Main message loop:
        while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
        {
            if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        CoUninitialize();
        return (int) msg.wParam;
    }
    
    
    
    //
    //  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
    //
    //  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
    //
    ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
    {
        WNDCLASSEXW wcex;
    
        wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    
        wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
        wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
        wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
        wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
        wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT1));
        wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
        wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
        wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1);
        wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
        wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));
    
        return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
    }
    
    //
    //   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
    //
    //   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
    //
    //   COMMENTS:
    //
    //        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
    //        create and display the main program window.
    //
    BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
    {
       hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable
    
       hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
          CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    
       if (!hWnd)
       {
          return FALSE;
       }
    
       ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
       UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    
       return TRUE;
    }
    
    //
    //  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
    //
    //  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
    //
    //  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
    //  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
    //  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
    //
    //
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            {
                int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
                // Parse the menu selections:
                switch (wmId)
                {
                case IDM_ABOUT:
                    DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                    break;
                case IDM_EXIT:
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                    break;
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
                }
            }
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            {
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
                EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            }
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Message handler for about box.
    INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    
        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
            {
                EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
            }
            break;
        }
        return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: You're probably looking at 1st chance exceptions they happen all the time and is normal behavior, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037933/what-is-a-first-chance-exception and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/ this is not a real issue, Microsoft is using this more and more in Windows (there were fewer of these years ago).

Comment: You also need to be checking all functions that return ``HRESULT`` for failure or success. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com).