# cdb sees "exception" in ISO C (not C++!) code from Win32 getaddrinfo()

Tags: c, exception, winapi, windbg

While debugging a multi-threaded (1024 worker threads) ISO C application compiled with Visual Studio 19, I get the message below from "cdb" (console version of WinDBG).

It looks like I get an "exception", but the code is plain ISO C - question is whether

1. is this correct?
2. how can I catch this exception ? Or, is this exception handled before `getaddrinfo()` returns to our code?

```
(2328.2010): Unknown exception - code 00000005 (first chance)
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site 00000080 002fa3d0
00007ffe ee8204c0 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69 00000080 002fa4b0
00007ffe ee820484 RPCRT4!RpcpRaiseException+0x34 00000080 002fa4e0
00007ffe ee8695e1 RPCRT4!RpcRaiseException+0x14 00000080 002fa510
00007ffe ee8cd562 RPCRT4!NdrSendReceive+0x41 00000080 002fa540
00007ffe ee8d05d0 RPCRT4!NdrpClientCall3+0x5d2 00000080 002fa8b0
00007ffe ec358cc1 RPCRT4!NdrClientCall3+0xf0 00000080 002fac40
00007ffe ec3589c3 DNSAPI!SyncResolverQueryRpc+0x171 00000080 002fae40
00007ffe ec35c327 DNSAPI!Rpc_ResolverQuery+0xc3 00000080 002faf10
00007ffe ec35bad6 DNSAPI!Query_PrivateExW+0x7a7 00000080 002fb740
00007ffe ec62b163 DNSAPI!DnsQueryEx+0x166 00000080 002fb9b0
00007ffe ec62af34 mswsock!SaBlob_Query+0xcb 00000080 002fba80
00007ffe ec62a60e mswsock!Rnr_DoDnsLookup+0x1ac 00000080 002fbb20
00007ffe ef44ba88 mswsock!Dns_NSPLookupServiceNext+0x1de
00000080 002fbf30 00007ffe ef44bc9c
WS2_32!NSPROVIDER::NSPLookupServiceNext+0x78 00000080 002fc000
00007ffe ef44bbbd WS2_32!NSQUERY::LookupServiceNext+0xa0
00000080 002fc080 00007ffe ef44bf7a WS2_32!WSALookupServiceNextW+0xdd
00000080 002fc0d0 00007ffe ef44c316 WS2_32!QueryDnsForFamily+0x1ae
00000080 002fca80 00007ffe ef4434da WS2_32!QueryDns+0x172
00000080 002fcb40 00007ffe ef445eac WS2_32!LookupAddressForName+0x122
00000080 002fcc50 00007ffe ef4437d5 WS2_32!GetAddrInfoW+0x38c
00000080 002fcdf0 00007ff6 a43b68cd WS2_32!getaddrinfo+0xc5
00007ff6 a439ca7c nfsd!nfs41_server_resolve(char * hostname =
0x00000080 002fd180 "derfwpc5131_ipv6", unsigned short port = 0x801,
struct __multi_addr4 * addrs = 0x00000080`002fd780)+0xed
```

We try to use `getaddrinfo()` in plain ISO C code, but get an exception.

Question is whether `getaddrinfo()` returns normally with an error return code, or does the exception just skip the return and exit the running thread?

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` does not throw an exception on failure, it returns an error code. That is very easy to verify for yourself.

Comment: A first chance exception is not uncommon in Win32 code. If it isn't handled then you'll get an unhandled exception which would terminate the program if not handled. [what is a first-chance-exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037933/what-is-a-first-chance-exception)  I assume there's an option yo ignore them in CDB as there is in the Visual Studio compiler, I just don't know what it is offhand.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to MSVC's [*Structured Exception Handling*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-170) extension.  It is distinct from C++ exception handling, and works in C and C++/CLR code.

Asynchronous exceptions (ones that are hardware exceptions such as divide by zero can be caught and handled by SEH (`/EHa`). I imagine even if you do not enable SEH, the debugger will trap them, where if ran outside of the debugger the process will just terminate.

Better in most cases to fix the bug that to add an exception handler for something that should not have happened.